# Why would I need costly software libraries for a layer 2/3 ethernet switch?

Tags: ethernet, programming

I am a novice electronics engineer and it is my first time implementing Ethernet links in my designs.

We recently bought a Connect Tech XDG007 GbE Switch, which will serve as a simple L2 Ethernet switch for several sub-systems to communicate together.

This COTS PCB has magnetics, power supplies, a memory IC and a Vitesse VSC7428X which handles all the switching (it has integrated PHYs). I thought "I can use this for the prototype, and then use the VSC chip on a board of my own for the *real* product".

However, when discussing this with the rep that sold me the XDG007, he informed of several software libraries that have to be purchased from the manufacturer (Microchip here) in order to get it working (he mentioned tens of thousands of $). He was unable to get into the technical details of exactly how and why, which is why I'm here.

My first impression, reading through Connect Tech's documentation, and skimming through some of Vitesse's application notes (AN1115 & AN1104), is that the ICLI (RS-232) and Web Interfaces (Ethernet) are available as soon as you boot up the device. Once each port is configured with the correct speed/protocol, it can perform the bare minimum switching function.

Here is the Software support matrix between software packages and Ethernet switch ICs by Microchip:
[image: Software support matrix between software packages and Ethernet switch ICs by Microchip]

I went on and read each of the software packages' pages that are "compatible" with the VSC7428, and still have no clue as to why I would want to pay for a SDK to perform simple ICLI commands that are perfectly described in available datasheets.

**So that leaves me with:** these software packages are designed to be used on embedded processors that have to interface with the VSC chips, but somehow can't use the ICLI link "as is"? Here I am making the assumption that these software packages are very expensive, and heavy, but that may not be the case. If they are just convenience drivers used to speed-up designs then I can see the point.

Did the rep tell me all this just so I would consider buying him more products instead of making my own switch (we have several mechanical constraints that make the use of a COTS board a PITA)?

I put this in EE because I considered it to be too low-level design considerations to be appropriate in SO.

14/06/21 edit : I have not forgotten, it's just that no one will give me a truthful even true-sounding answer (called all major manufacturers and they redirected me mostly to suppliers who most of the time wouldn't even answer my emails).

Comment: Ask the salesperson to why you need to spend that money on software licence, and what is the software licence for? Most Ethernet switch chips work as switches without any configuration from a MCU to control it or configuration EEPROM. Even if it requires configuration, a medium level MCU with MDIO interface (or entry level MCU with GPIO) can configure it. Maybe the salesperson changes tone when you say that you will buy other chips that don't need such a licence to control them.

Comment: I asked him exactly that, and his answer was mainly comprised of networking and programming buzzwords that signaled that he didn't know half the words he used. I didn't call him out on it since I may still need some of his products :p He also told me that every manufacturer uses this technique to "lure" engineers into buying the software after the fact.

Comment: Well, the sales rep works for someone who makes a living selling switches, right? Telling you exactly what you need to know to not need his products might not be in his or his company's interest. Call a microsemi representative, you're planning to buy their products later on, right? Call the competion (Realtek)'s local distributor, too.

Comment: I agree with Marcus. Call Microchip and get the information directly from them instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will call Microchip, Broadcom and Realtek to know for certain. I will post an answer to help people wondering the same thing.